# SUM is returning double value with multiple left joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a SQL query in which SUM aggregate function returns all values just double. I exactly not understand, how it is happening. Here is the query

```
 SELECT 
  st.id,
  u.id AS user_id,
  st.student_code,
  spd.first_name,
  spd.middle_name,
  spd.last_name,
  spd.birth_date,
  classes.`class_name`,
  sections.`section_name`,
  sed.`roll_no`,
  sgd.first_name AS gardian_first_name,
  sgd.middle_name AS gardian_middle_name,
  sgd.last_name AS gardian_last_name,
  sgd.contact_no,
  SUM(sfd.`final_fee`) AS total_calculated_fee,
  SUM(sfd.`total_paid_amount`) AS total_paid_amount,
  SUM(sfd.`total_due_amount`) AS total_due_amount 
FROM
  students st 
  LEFT JOIN users u 
    ON st.`id` = u.`student_id` 
  LEFT JOIN student_personal_details spd 
    ON st.`id` = spd.`student_id` 
  LEFT JOIN student_gardian_details sgd 
    ON st.`id` = sgd.`student_id` 
  LEFT JOIN student_education_details sed 
    ON st.`id` = sed.`student_id` 
  LEFT JOIN student_hostel_details shd 
    ON st.`id` = shd.`student_id` 

  LEFT JOIN classes 
    ON sed.`class_id` = classes.`class_id` 
  LEFT JOIN sections 
    ON sed.`section_id` = sections.`id` 
    LEFT JOIN student_fee_details sfd 
    ON st.`id` = sfd.`student_id` 
WHERE st.is_active = 1 AND st.`id` = 2
GROUP BY sfd.`student_id` 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

I used distinct in all three fields but the middle one is returning 1/4 value.
Could anyone help me

Comment: You'll get multiplied values if at least two of those joins end up matching *multiple* rows for the same value - say that `classes` matches two rows, `a` and `b`, and that `sections` matches two rows, `1` and `2`. Your result set will now contain *4* rows, in all combinations: `a,1`, `a,2`, `b,1` and `b,2`. Without having *your* data, I can't tell you *which* of the joins this is happening for, but it is happening.

Comment: So what do you suggest??

Comment: That you need to work out which of your join condition(s) aren't causing 1-1 matches. Again, we *don't have your data*

Comment: Remove the 'group by' and look at the returned rows to see which are being duplicated.

Comment: Use sub queries and join them.

Comment: actually I removed group by and all three sum and then every row is being repeated six times

Comment: Now, you start to 'debug' the query and find out which joins are causing the duplication and why. Build the query slowly adding tables one at a time along with appropriate conditions. You will see when 'duplicates' start to appear.

Comment: Yes, I've found that if I remove the first left join then the data is correct but I need that. because the row is repating three time for that

Comment: Then there are *3* rows in `users` with the *same* `student_id` - you need to add more conditions to your `on` to reduce that down to one row.